# Expresss not receiving all query string parameters using curl

Tags: node.js, curl, express

In Express 4 I'm not receiving all the query string paramters, only the first one. Curl shows some weird output that I don't know how what means..
I'm using cors and mongoose-pagination modules.

What's happening here?

Using curl:
curl http://localhost:3000/products?_dc=1465158748756&page=1&start=0&limit=25

In app.js:

```
//Enable CORS
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/products', products);
```

In product controller:

```
/* GET products listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var page = req.query.page ? 1 : req.query.page;
  //var start = req.query.start;
  var limit = req.query.limit ? 1 : req.query.limit;
  db.product.paginate({}, { page: page, limit: limit }, function(err, p){
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        //Error
        res.status = 500;
        return res.send(new Error(err)); 
      }
      return res.send(p);
    });
});
```

The req.query only contains the first parameter:

```
req.query
Object
_dc: "1465158748756"
__proto__: Object
```

This is the curl's output, I don't know how to interpret this:

```
oscar@dlp-AOD255E:~/node/HomeInventoryServer$ curl http://localhost:3000/products?_dc=1465158748756&page=1&start=0&limit=25
[1] 3471
[2] 3472
[3] 3473
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just for the records, it seems that I need to put the url inside quotes " as curl interprets it in a different way.

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/products?_dc=1465158748756&page=1&start=0&limit=25"
```

Comment: also check this:
var page = req.query.page ? 1 : req.query.page;

this will set page to 1, even if you have set req.query.page. A better way to do this is:

var page = req.query.page || 1

Comment: @Joenesy Thank you very much for that advise!